# Laravel extending Eloquent

Tags: php, oop, laravel, eloquent

Im fairly new to Laravel, namespaces and classes. I have an App-specific class which is autoloaded correctly and has it's own namespace. This class extends Eloquent.

What I want to do is find ways to optimize my code. Here is a sample one:

```
$collection = Collection::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->with('photos')->get();
```

So I have a Collection model which extends my own Appspecific abstract class. Nothing is wrong with the above code, however I will be doing it a lot and I would love to optimize it for readability. Something like this:

```
$collection = Collection::getMine()->with('photos')->get();
```

Now in my app-specific class I have this:

```
public static function getMine() {
    if(\Auth::guest())
        return false;

    return $this->where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id); //would not work coz im not in object context

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing this in the correct class? Should I be doing this on another class that extends something else, say BuilderClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Eloquent's scope methods](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
public function scopeGetMine ($query)
{
    if(\Auth::guest()) return false;

    return $query->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);

}
```

Then just use it as you wish:

```
$collection = Collection::getMine()->with('photos')->get();
```